# Как при нажатии на PrtSc сделать скрин?

Tags: linux, screenshots

Установил когда то давно Linux Mint KDE ,но сегодня поставил другую графическую оболочку `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` и установилась lubuntu чего и ожидал , работает безупречно всё тип топ но при нажатии на PrtSc не появляется скрин как в других версиях Linux. Как это можно исправить ?Конечно использование `shutter` всё решает но хотелось бы функции

Comment: А Вы уверенны, что скриншот не делается. В Lubuntu, по умолчанию, при нажатии PrtSc, скрин экрана без уведомлений в домашнюю директорию складывается или в изображения.

Comment: я щас гляну , если так

Comment: сделайте ответом - я не знал этого

Comment: Установив метапакет `lubuntu-desktop`, вы лишь меняете рабочее окружение, ваша операционная система по прежнему остаётся Linux Mint и она очень сильно отличается от Lubuntu! Не советую ставить несколько DE на рабочей системе, вы тем самым превращаете её в помойку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Lubuntu, по умолчанию, при нажатии `PrtSc`, скриншот экрана без уведомлений в домашнюю директорию складывается или в изображения.

Comment: И отвечает за это scrot

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов, для того чтобы сделать скриншот:

1. PrtScr+Shift
   открывает ножницы + возможность сохранить по указанному адресу
2. PrtScr+Shift+Ctr
   тоже самое, но без интерфейса сохранения фото